# Connecting bulk capacitor board via header or standoff?

Tags: analog, layout, inductance, decoupling-capacitor

I am routing a 2 board design that are stacked on the top of each other. The lower board (inverter board) contain the power transistors and a separate board contain the bulk DC-link capacitors for the inverter.

I know that we should reduce ESL and ESR of the capacitors and reduce power loop. The stacked height between the boards is 20 mm.
My question: How should I connect the 2 boards together?

Options:

1. Use solder-able brass tin plated standoff and solder it on the inverter board and use a stainless steel M3 screw on the top board.
2. Use standard 2.54 mm header. Something like 10 pins for positive and 10 pins for negative.
3. Solder a sheet of 1 mm thick copper or 10 mm2 stranded wire on both boards, with a disadvantage of being permanent.

I have not found a way to estimate the resistance and inductance of each solution.

Comment: What voltage, current and switching frequency are we talking about here? What does each board do? You want your capacitors as close to the output transistors as possible.

Comment: Should be no issue. Interleave forward and return current lines in the connector to minimize the loop (and hence radiation). ESL is pretty much irrelevant for bulk Al caps and so is the resistance of the header. You must put low ESL caps on the inverter board in any case though.

Comment: @winny : 50v 100A 20khz . board 1 is 3-phase inverter with gate drive . board 2 is Alumimum bulk caps only .

Comment: @tobalt : inverter board contain ceramic caps 1uF at each inverter half bridge. the bulk caps are aluminum . you have said "ESL is pretty much irrelevant for bulk Al caps and so is the resistance of the header" . however as i learned from senior engineers before than the legs of the capacitors should be kept as short as possible to reduce ESL and ESR , that's why it is not recommended to place Alu capacitor on horizontally and bend its leg. So how come the headers will not affect this ???

Comment: At 20 kHz and 100 A, you will need very low inductance and probably film capacitors too. You’ll be struggling with off-board capacitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly speaking, expect 1nH/mm of length for a run.  This is the base scale factor.  There is also a geometry factor: the wider and flatter the connection, or the more in parallel, the less the inductance.  So, parallel facing sheets are better than edge-on (hence why we use pours on PCBs), and alternating pins in parallel are better than single pins (or whole groups of pins).

This is true of any parallel conductors carrying complementary currents.  So, connectors, cables, traces, component leads, whatever.  It's why faster and more powerful ICs have multiple power pins (usually in adjacent VCC/GND pairs).

There's also the matter of how much inductance you can tolerate.  If dI/dt is low, it might be enough to use a couple brass standoffs and no local bypass.  Else, local bypass (film or ceramic) caps can be placed on the inverter, and then provide some means to deal with the resonant circuit thus formed (the local caps will resonate with the connection inductance, probably at a harmonic of Fsw; the amplitude needs to be kept within reasonable limits, for operational or EMC reasons).

You can also consider dividing it in the other direction: cut the bulk cap into groups and put them on each inverter channel.  This is most feasible when multiple outputs are already needed (e.g. 3-phase motor drive), or can be used (e.g. consider splitting a high-power single buck converter into a multi-channel phase interleave design).  If nothing else, a single (synchronized) output can be split across multiple inverters, using 0° power combiners to wire them in parallel, or transformers in series, as the case may be.  (Example: induction heating, where a single AC output at frequency is required; a modular design can have inverters wired in series using individual transformers per module, or in parallel using power combiners.)

Note that multiphase interleave applies to class D (audio, true sine inverter, etc.) applications as well.  I'm not aware offhand of any controllers designed in this way, but any current-mode scheme can be wired in parallel trivially, given a suitable control scheme of course.

Incidentally, note that "bridged" class D can also be described as the series connection of two such amplifiers (two being the special case that doesn't require a transformer, as long as the load doesn't require a ground reference).  Which could therefore switch at some phase offset.  (Again, I don't know offhand if any controllers do this, or just run complementary drive to the H-bridge and that's that.)

In any case, phase interleave allows reduction of input and output ripple currents, by cancelling out the fundamental (and applicable low harmonics) between channels.  Maybe this isn't important as you need the bulk capacitance for other reasons (mains filtering?), but it can indeed save on overall size when the capacitors are only there to handle the switching ripple.

As for connection schemes: bolted standoffs, quick-connect terminals, and other blade-type connectors, can do a fine job.  Generic mezzanine 2.54mm headers aren't rated for much current, but connector families are available with attractive ratings (and often features like shrouded housings or individual pins, offering substantial voltage ratings e.g. 600V).  And heavier terminals, at wider pitch, are readily available too.

Regarding bolted connections: beware that FR-4 cold-flows over time, and also softens when very hot.  Use spring-loaded connections, such as conical (Belleville) washers, to ensure contact pressure over life of the equipment.  Avoid bare copper/brass contacts, and do not mix platings (e.g. gold and tin); tin or HASL on the PCB, and tin-plated brass (or whatnot) hardware, are a fine combination.  Also avoid using screws as contact, if possible; not like to avoid them entirely, don't go to the trouble of insulating the screw -- just make the standoff, nut or terminal block the preferred current flow path.  Screws aren't great as solitary conductors due to the thinner cross section, and high tension.  (That said, in the event you must use them this way, consider brass or bronze bolts over steel.  This can also be a helpful choice around strong AC fields -- the bolt head itself can be induction-heated by nearby current flows, and a higher conductivity (thermally and electrically) material helps greatly.)

Also consider using soldered nuts or terminal blocks for these connections.  A terminal like Keystone 8197 provides secure through holes, a lead frame to somewhat separate terminal stress from the pins (I say "somewhat" because they are still quite stocky bits of metal), and a metal clamping face that requires no special considerations (a bolt, and maybe a lockwasher if you like, will hold reliably).

Generally speaking, where you have an array of pins/terminals, alternate +/- to reduce inductance.  Roughly speaking, one pair of connections is somewhere between a parallel-wire and parallel-plate transmission line segment, depending on geometry (cross-section); this will have a geometry factor around 1/4, i.e. closer to 0.3 nH/mm inductivity.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_quad_cable)  When you use more pairs, if they're distant from each other, they simply act in parallel, so impedance goes down proportional to number.  When pairs are close together (or indeed overlapping, as you might view the case of a three-wire `+ - +` arrangement), and of opposing polarity/direction, their fields partially cancel and even less inductance can be had.  (Consider the case of [star quad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_quad_cable) for example, which uses as much wire as two twisted pairs in parallel, but achieves about half the impedance!)  In a two-row header, a checkerboard pattern:

```
+ - + - + -
- + - + - +
```

can give extremely low inductance.  Obviously, you'll need to connect to such a pin array using plane pairs in the PCB.

You might also have considerations like, maybe you need a fairly high current path, but you also need low enough inductance, juuust low enough that it's feasible using headers -- so you might opt for the headers, which might be slightly more expensive or tedious or something to use/buy, but which actually save the cost of more bypassing and snubbing on the inverter board, or something like that.  Whereas if you needed very low inductance, the header might still not be enough and it won't matter which connector you choose and local bypass/snubbing is required so might as well go with the cheapest/simplest option; whereas if you don't need low inductance at all, the larger connector is fine regardless.  (This is very unspecific; just to say, there may be certain edge cases, or lucky coincidences, where choosing another option can be better overall, though it might not seem such a likely option at first glance.)

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_quad_cable) The hand-wave that I find easy to remember is: the impedance of free space is 377Ω; a twisted-pair or parallel-line transmission line is around 100Ω, or 1/4th, so the capacitance is 4 times higher, and inductance 4 times lower, than \$\epsilon_0\$ and \$\mu_0\$ respectively.  (\$Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$, remember.)  Which, recall, have units of F or H per length, so, multiply by line length to get overall C or L.  Of which we're mainly interested in L here, because \$Z \ll Z_0\$.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic "it depends" question.
Mostly, this is a cost/performance balance. How much degradation in performance you can tolerate will dictate the cost, as well as other practical considerations.

Option 1 is cheap, and has the advantage of doubling up as your mounting hardware, so decreases costs, and possibly also decreases your assembly costs. If properly assembled, then this is also a good low-resistance option. Dont force yourself to have an even pattern of these at the expense of your current paths - I mean you won't have to place these at the corners of your board, you can place them in the middle, in pairs as well so each regulator has a sensible return path for its ground.

Option 2, is probably the worst of both worlds as is. .1" header can be a bit fussy and doesn't normally have good current ratings. But you can buy board-to-board connectors designed for this kind of thing, so if you were to go with one of those then this is a better idea. I've used UMPS-02 from samtec for example.

Option 3, is very cheap, but like you say permanent(ish). It's up to you to decide if this is a problem. Also, the length of the wire looping around is certain to add an inductance, possibly/probably more than the previous two.

Do you have enough capacitance on the inverter board to properly smooth and stabilize the regulators? Having any ripple or AC currents going between the boards will be an EMI nightmare. If you need these capacitors to stabilize the regulators, then any ESL/R (as you know) will degrade the performance. Getting a firm estimate for these values is going to be difficult (at least for me). Usually, components would be rated for a current, rather than a DC resistance, and the series inductance will depend on the routing as well.
Can you even out the design so there are half the regulators on one board - with their bulk caps - and half on the other?